# Meaning of a seal

Tags: meaning, seal

[image]

Could you tell me the meaning of this seal? I got it as a present from China but I don't know what it means...

Comment: The character 瓦 is a family name  and 尼亚 is a given one so its safe to assume its a name seal.  Typical name seals would also contain an additional character 印 signifying that it was a name seal.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a transliteration of a non-Chinese name. 瓦尼亚 rendered in Pinyin romanization is wǎ ní yà. Unless a set of characters was provided to the person who carved the seal, that is how the carver decided to transliterate your username (and personal name?), Anja.

Comment: Thanks @Anja. If you like my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer!